# The syntax of the command is incorrect in IF condition while executing Batch File

Tags: batch-file

In the below code i am getting The syntax of the command is incorrect error. Most probably on the first IF statement. But sometime it works smoothly. don't know why? Please help

```
@ECHO OFF
IF "%~1" == "" (
    ECHO Please provide file location
    GOTO End
) ELSE (
    echo %1
    SET FILE=%1
    IF NOT EXIST %FILE% (
        ECHO Invalid File. Please provide correct path of file.
        GOTO End
    )
    echo file found
)
:End
echo End of script
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
IF "%~1" == "" (
    ECHO Please provide file location
    GOTO End
) ELSE (
    echo %1
    SET "FILE=%~1"
    IF NOT EXIST "!FILE!" (
        ECHO Invalid File. Please provide correct path of file.
        GOTO End
    )
    echo file found
)
:End
echo End of script
endlocal
```

You need delayed expansion as you set a variable inside brackets.The variable stays undefined until end of brackets and cmd parser sees :

```
   IF NOT EXIST  (
            ECHO Invalid File. Please provide correct path of file.
            GOTO End
        )
```

which is a syntax error detected before `if` execution.

[link1](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)
[link2](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/variableexpansion.php)

Comment: Brackets? This could be misleading. Think you mean 'parenthesis'? = ( )